# Combining designMode on/off bookmarklets into one toggling bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, contenteditable, designmode

I'm looking to combine these 2 bookmarklets into 1 bookmarklet that toggles the designMode on and off:

On: `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true';%20document.designMode='on';%20void%200`

Off: `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='false';%20document.designMode='off';%20void%200`

I had tried some if else statements but can't seem to detect if designMode was on or not. So not sure what I was doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLVED** (*i had typos, oops)* **:**

```
javascript:(

function () {
    if (document.documentElement.contentEditable === false || document.designMode === "off") {
        document.body.contentEditable='true';
        document.designMode='on';
        void 0;
    } else if (document.documentElement.contentEditable === true || document.designMode === "on") {
        document.body.contentEditable='false';
        document.designMode='off';
        void 0;
    }
})();
```

Comment: The one liner is:

`javascript:(function () {if (document.documentElement.contentEditable === false || document.designMode === "off") {document.body.contentEditable='true';document.designMode='on';void 0;} else if (document.documentElement.contentEditable === true || document.designMode === "on") {document.body.contentEditable='false';document.designMode='off';void 0;}})();`

Comment: p.s. All browsers support bookmarklets with multi-lines.

Comment: FWIW, 10 years later, here's a more compact version: `javascript:((d,ce,dm)=>(d.body[ce]==true||d[dm]=="on"?(d.body[ce]="false",d[dm]="off"):(d.body[ce]="true",d[dm]="on"))&&void 0)(document,"contentEditable","designMode")`

Answer (score -3):

This works on Google Chrome

```
   data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```